# group_by operation in dplyr vs data.table for fast implementation

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

```
dat <- data.frame(yearID = rep(1:10000, each = 12),
                  monthID = rep(1:12, times = 10000),
                  x1 = rnorm(120000),
                  x2 = rnorm(120000),
                  x3 = rnorm(120000),
                  x4 = rnorm(120000),
                  x5 = rnorm(120000),
                  x6 = rnorm(120000),
                  p.start = 6,
                  p.end = 7,
                  m.start = 8,
                  m.end = 9,
                  h.start = 10,
                  h.end = 11)
```

I need to do some operations on the above data which is described below after my current solution

```
library(dplyr)

start_time <- Sys.time()

df1 <- dat %>% 
       tidyr::gather(., index_name, value, x1:x6) %>%
       dplyr::filter(!index_name %in% c('x5','x6')) %>%
       dplyr::group_by(yearID, index_name) %>%
       dplyr::summarise(p.start.val = sum(value[monthID == p.start]),
                        p.val = sum(value[monthID >= p.start & monthID <= p.end]),
                        m.val = sum(value[monthID >= m.start & monthID <= m.end]),
                        h.val = sum(value[monthID >= h.start & monthID <= h.end]),
                        h.end.val = sum(value[monthID == h.end])) %>%
       tidyr::gather(., variable, value, p.start.val:h.end.val) %>%
       dplyr::mutate(new.col.name = paste0(index_name,'_',variable)) %>%
       dplyr::select(-index_name, -variable) %>% 
       tidyr::spread(., new.col.name, value) %>%
       dplyr::mutate(yearRef = 2018)

colnames(df1) <-  sub(".val", "", colnames(df1))    

df2 <- dat %>% 
       tidyr::gather(., index_name, value, x1:x6) %>%
       dplyr::filter(index_name %in% c('x4','x6')) %>%
       dplyr::group_by(yearID, index_name) %>%
       dplyr::summarise(p.end.val = value[monthID == p.end],
                        m.end.val = value[monthID == m.end],
                        h.end.val = value[monthID == h.end]) %>%
       tidyr::gather(., variable, value, p.end.val:h.end.val) %>%
       dplyr::mutate(new.col.name = paste0(index_name,'_',variable)) %>%
       dplyr::select(-index_name, -variable) %>% 
       tidyr::spread(., new.col.name, value) %>%
       dplyr::mutate(yearRef = 2018)

colnames(df2) <-  sub(".val", "", colnames(df2))

final.dat <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = c( "yearID", "yearRef"), all.x=TRUE), list(df1,df2))

 end_time <- Sys.time()

 end_time - start_time

 # Time difference of 2.054761 secs
```

What I want to do is:

- for variable `x1` to `x4`, I want to sum them for different months as shown in `df1`
- for variable `x5` to `x6`, I want to select the values for selected month for each year as shown in `df2`

My code above works fine but takes quite a time if the size of `dat` increases i.e. if number of years become 20000 instead of 10000. I am wondering if someone could help me with a `data.table` to implement the above solution which I hope would make this faster. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at `dtplyr`, it is using the syntax of `dplyr` but executing in `data.table`. https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr Could be an easy way to speed up your code

Comment: Thanks @fmarm. This is quite interesting and new to me. I tried to use the package but running into error `Error in UseMethod("gather_") : 
  no applicable method for 'gather_' applied to an object of class "c('dtplyr_step_first', 'dtplyr_step')"`. I guess the `gather` function from `tidyr` is not applicable for dtplyr?

Comment: can you explain in words your problem? maybe there is an even better tidyverse code for your problem other than your current implementation.

Comment: One issue is that you're talking about `dtplyr`, a *"Data table backend for dplyr"*. While there is a [PR to add `dt_pivot_wider`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr/pull/121) (hint, `pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` are intended as the replacements for `spread` and `gather`, all from the `tidyr` package), I see no other mention of `tidyr` in the `dtplyr` docs.

Comment: As a relatively-recent adopter of `data.table` into "expensive" (large) tables, I find the combination of `magrittr::%>%` with `data.table`'s referential semantics to be not completely unintuitive. While the "verbs" are not nearly as declarative as in `dplyr` (as evidenced in my answer), I don't think it's too difficult to see the parallels. Add in other parallels like `fifelse` (`dplyr::if_else`), `lapply` and `Map` (`purrr::map` and `purrr::pmap`), and some others, it might be less attractive but is still not abhorrent to read. (Just my humble opinion. I still use both daily. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll run this on `df1` only, since from there the pattern is easily repeatable.

Notes:

- I'm using `magrittr` solely to help break out each step in the chain, as each of `dplyr`'s *verbs`are directly translatable. It is not difficult to convert this into a non-`magrittr` pipeline. The benefit of using it (as is also the case with tidyverse pipes) is, in my opinion, readability and therefore maintainability.

### The Answer

I'll walk through the steps below.

```r
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

as.data.table(dat) %>%
  melt(., measure.vars = grep("^x[0-9]+", colnames(.)),
       variable.name = "index_name", variable.factor = FALSE) %>%
  .[ !index_name %in% c("x5", "x6"), ] %>%
  .[, .(
    p.start.val = sum(value[monthID == p.start]),
    p.val = sum(value[monthID >= p.start & monthID <= p.end]),
    m.val = sum(value[monthID >= m.start & monthID <= m.end]),
    h.val = sum(value[monthID >= h.start & monthID <= h.end]),
    h.end.val = sum(value[monthID == h.end])
  ), by = .(yearID, index_name) ] %>%
  melt(., id.vars = 1:2, variable.factor = FALSE) %>%
  .[, new.col.name := paste0(index_name, "_", variable) ] %>%
  .[, c("index_name", "variable") := NULL ] %>%
  dcast(., yearID ~ new.col.name) %>%
  .[, yearRef := 2018 ]
```

---

### Steps:

Notes for the steps:

- In the walk-through, I add `dplyr::arrange_all()` and `.[order(.),]` to the end of each intermediate pipe just so that we have apples-to-apples comparisons.
- You did not include a random seed for your sample. I used `set.seed(42)`, so to compare your console with what I'm showing, you'll need to set this seed and regenerate `dat`.
- Each code block continues from the previous step's code, I shorten all repeated code to `... %>%` for brevity to make this answer much less voluminous.

The steps:

1. `tidyr::gather` to `data.table::melt`. There's likely a better way than `grep` to select ranges of columns in `data.table::melt`, but while `as.data.table(dat)[, -(x1:x6)]` works as one might infer, the same column-ranging does not work within `melt`.

   ```r
   dat %>% 
     tidyr::gather(., index_name, value, x1:x6) %>%
     arrange_all() %>% head() # just for comparison
   # # A tibble: 6 x 10
   #   yearID monthID p.start p.end m.start m.end h.start h.end index_name  value
   #    <int>   <int>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
   # 1      1       1       6     7       8     9      10    11 x1          1.37 
   # 2      1       1       6     7       8     9      10    11 x2         -0.483
   # 3      1       1       6     7       8     9      10    11 x3         -0.314
   # 4      1       1       6     7       8     9      10    11 x4         -2.23 
   # 5      1       1       6     7       8     9      10    11 x5         -0.717
   # 6      1       1       6     7       8     9      10    11 x6         -1.04 
   as.data.table(dat) %>%
     melt(., measure.vars = grep("^x[0-9]+", colnames(.)),
          variable.name = "index_name", variable.factor = FALSE) %>%
     .[order(.),] %>% head() # just for comparison
   #    yearID monthID p.start p.end m.start m.end h.start h.end index_name      value
   # 1:      1       1       6     7       8     9      10    11         x1  1.3709584
   # 2:      1       1       6     7       8     9      10    11         x2 -0.4831687
   # 3:      1       1       6     7       8     9      10    11         x3 -0.3139498
   # 4:      1       1       6     7       8     9      10    11         x4 -2.2323282
   # 5:      1       1       6     7       8     9      10    11         x5 -0.7167575
   # 6:      1       1       6     7       8     9      10    11         x6 -1.0357630
   ```
2. add in `dplyr::filter` and `dplyr::summarise` (grouped); I literally just copied the new variables' assignments from `summarise(...)` into `.( ... )` block, no change was necessary.

   ```r
   ... %>%
     dplyr::filter(!index_name %in% c('x5','x6')) %>%
     dplyr::group_by(yearID, index_name) %>%
     dplyr::summarise(p.start.val = sum(value[monthID == p.start]),
                      p.val = sum(value[monthID >= p.start & monthID <= p.end]),
                      m.val = sum(value[monthID >= m.start & monthID <= m.end]),
                      h.val = sum(value[monthID >= h.start & monthID <= h.end]),
                      h.end.val = sum(value[monthID == h.end])) %>%
     arrange_all() %>% head() # just for comparison
   # # A tibble: 6 x 7
   # # Groups:   yearID [2]
   #   yearID index_name p.start.val  p.val   m.val  h.val h.end.val
   #    <int> <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
   # 1      1 x1             -0.106   1.41   1.92    1.24      1.30 
   # 2      1 x2              0.573  -0.516 -2.29   -3.54     -0.990
   # 3      1 x3              0.767   0.455  0.461   2.28      2.08 
   # 4      1 x4             -0.0559 -1.11  -0.0975 -0.326    -0.483
   # 5      2 x1             -2.66   -5.10   1.01   -1.95     -0.172
   # 6      2 x2              0.342  -0.546  0.605   1.51      1.25 
   ... %>%
     .[ !index_name %in% c("x5", "x6"), ] %>%
     .[, .(
       p.start.val = sum(value[monthID == p.start]),
       p.val = sum(value[monthID >= p.start & monthID <= p.end]),
       m.val = sum(value[monthID >= m.start & monthID <= m.end]),
       h.val = sum(value[monthID >= h.start & monthID <= h.end]),
       h.end.val = sum(value[monthID == h.end])
     ), by = .(yearID, index_name) ] %>%
     .[order(.),] %>% head(.) # just for comparison
   #    yearID index_name p.start.val      p.val       m.val      h.val  h.end.val
   # 1:      1         x1 -0.10612452  1.4053975  1.92376468  1.2421556  1.3048697
   # 2:      1         x2  0.57306337 -0.5164756 -2.28861552 -3.5367198 -0.9901743
   # 3:      1         x3  0.76706512  0.4546020  0.46096277  2.2819246  2.0842981
   # 4:      1         x4 -0.05589648 -1.1093361 -0.09748514 -0.3260778 -0.4825699
   # 5:      2         x1 -2.65645542 -5.0969223  1.01347475 -1.9532258 -0.1719174
   # 6:      2         x2  0.34227065 -0.5457969  0.60537738  1.5136450  1.2498633
   ```
3. `tidyr::gather` again

   ```r
   ... %>%
     tidyr::gather(., variable, value, p.start.val:h.end.val) %>%
     arrange_all() %>% head() # just for comparison
   # # A tibble: 6 x 4
   # # Groups:   yearID [1]
   #   yearID index_name variable     value
   #    <int> <chr>      <chr>        <dbl>
   # 1      1 x1         h.end.val    1.30 
   # 2      1 x1         h.val        1.24 
   # 3      1 x1         m.val        1.92 
   # 4      1 x1         p.start.val -0.106
   # 5      1 x1         p.val        1.41 
   # 6      1 x2         h.end.val   -0.990
   ... %>%
     melt(., id.vars = 1:2, variable.factor = FALSE) %>%
     .[order(.),] %>% head(.) # just for comparison
   #    yearID index_name    variable      value
   # 1:      1         x1   h.end.val  1.3048697
   # 2:      1         x1       h.val  1.2421556
   # 3:      1         x1       m.val  1.9237647
   # 4:      1         x1 p.start.val -0.1061245
   # 5:      1         x1       p.val  1.4053975
   # 6:      1         x2   h.end.val -0.9901743
   ```
4. `tidyr::spread` to `data.table::dcast`

   ```r
   ... %>%
     dplyr::mutate(new.col.name = paste0(index_name,'_',variable)) %>%
     dplyr::select(-index_name, -variable) %>% 
     tidyr::spread(., new.col.name, value) %>%
     arrange_all() %>% head() # just for comparison
   # # A tibble: 6 x 21
   # # Groups:   yearID [6]
   #   yearID x1_h.end.val x1_h.val x1_m.val x1_p.start.val x1_p.val x2_h.end.val x2_h.val x2_m.val x2_p.start.val x2_p.val x3_h.end.val x3_h.val x3_m.val x3_p.start.val x3_p.val x4_h.end.val x4_h.val x4_m.val x4_p.start.val x4_p.val
   #    <int>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>    <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>          <dbl>    <dbl>
   # 1      1        1.30     1.24     1.92          -0.106    1.41        -0.990   -3.54   -2.29            0.573   -0.516        2.08     2.28     0.461          0.767    0.455      -0.483   -0.326   -0.0975        -0.0559  -1.11  
   # 2      2       -0.172   -1.95     1.01          -2.66    -5.10         1.25     1.51    0.605           0.342   -0.546       -1.38    -0.731    0.443         -0.725   -1.17       -0.623   -1.91     1.49          -0.806   -0.717 
   # 3      3        0.505   -0.104    1.74          -0.640   -0.185        0.570    1.68   -2.24           -0.103   -1.02        -1.36    -2.50    -0.918          1.36     1.26        0.0847  -0.280    0.699          0.114   -0.582 
   # 4      4       -0.811   -0.379   -2.09          -0.361    0.397       -0.782    0.110  -0.0187         -0.641   -0.149       -1.47    -2.45    -1.27           0.418    0.131       0.0582   0.885    0.784          0.998   -0.0115
   # 5      5       -2.99    -2.90     0.956          0.643    0.733        0.165    0.382   1.46            1.48     2.16        -0.451   -0.213   -0.357          0.222    0.686      -0.949   -0.156    1.23           1.35     0.908 
   # 6      6       -1.04    -0.322    1.96           1.30     1.64         0.838   -0.406   1.86            0.863    2.11         0.479    2.37    -1.13          -1.22    -1.63       -0.970    0.0391  -1.08           0.683   -1.24  
   ... %>%
     .[, new.col.name := paste0(index_name, "_", variable) ] %>%
     .[, c("index_name", "variable") := NULL ] %>%
     dcast(., yearID ~ new.col.name) %>%
     .[order(.),] %>% head(.) # just for comparison
   #    yearID x1_h.end.val   x1_h.val   x1_m.val x1_p.start.val   x1_p.val x2_h.end.val   x2_h.val    x2_m.val x2_p.start.val   x2_p.val x3_h.end.val   x3_h.val   x3_m.val x3_p.start.val   x3_p.val x4_h.end.val    x4_h.val    x4_m.val x4_p.start.val    x4_p.val
   # 1:      1    1.3048697  1.2421556  1.9237647     -0.1061245  1.4053975   -0.9901743 -3.5367198 -2.28861552      0.5730634 -0.5164756    2.0842981  2.2819246  0.4609628      0.7670651  0.4546020  -0.48256993 -0.32607779 -0.09748514    -0.05589648 -1.10933614
   # 2:      2   -0.1719174 -1.9532258  1.0134748     -2.6564554 -5.0969223    1.2498633  1.5136450  0.60537738      0.3422707 -0.5457969   -1.3790815 -0.7305400  0.4429124     -0.7249950 -1.1681343  -0.62293711 -1.90725766  1.48980773    -0.80634526 -0.71692479
   # 3:      3    0.5049551 -0.1039713  1.7399409     -0.6399949 -0.1845448    0.5697303  1.6768675 -2.24285021     -0.1029872 -1.0245616   -1.3608773 -2.5029906 -0.9178704      1.3641160  1.2619892   0.08468983 -0.27967757  0.69899862     0.11429665 -0.58216791
   # 4:      4   -0.8113932 -0.3785752 -2.0949859     -0.3610573  0.3971059   -0.7823128  0.1098614 -0.01867344     -0.6414615 -0.1488759   -1.4653210 -2.4476336 -1.2718183      0.4179297  0.1311655   0.05823201  0.88484095  0.78382293     0.99795594 -0.01147192
   # 5:      5   -2.9930901 -2.9032572  0.9558396      0.6428993  0.7326600    0.1645109  0.3819658  1.45532687      1.4820236  2.1608213   -0.4513016 -0.2129462 -0.3572757      0.2221201  0.6855960  -0.94859958 -0.15646638  1.23051588     1.34645936  0.90755241
   # 6:      6   -1.0431189 -0.3222408  1.9592347      1.3025426  1.6383908    0.8379162 -0.4059827  1.86142674      0.8626753  2.1076609    0.4792767  2.3683451 -1.1252801     -1.2213407 -1.6339743  -0.96979464  0.03912882 -1.08199221     0.68254513 -1.23950872
   ```
5. finish it up

   ```r
   df1a <- df1 %>% arrange_all()
   head(df1a)
   # # A tibble: 6 x 22
   # # Groups:   yearID [6]
   #   yearID x1_h.end   x1_h   x1_m x1_p.start   x1_p x2_h.end   x2_h    x2_m x2_p.start   x2_p x3_h.end   x3_h   x3_m x3_p.start   x3_p x4_h.end    x4_h    x4_m x4_p.start    x4_p yearRef
   #    <int>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
   # 1      1    1.30   1.24   1.92      -0.106  1.41    -0.990 -3.54  -2.29        0.573 -0.516    2.08   2.28   0.461      0.767  0.455  -0.483  -0.326  -0.0975    -0.0559 -1.11      2018
   # 2      2   -0.172 -1.95   1.01      -2.66  -5.10     1.25   1.51   0.605       0.342 -0.546   -1.38  -0.731  0.443     -0.725 -1.17   -0.623  -1.91    1.49      -0.806  -0.717     2018
   # 3      3    0.505 -0.104  1.74      -0.640 -0.185    0.570  1.68  -2.24       -0.103 -1.02    -1.36  -2.50  -0.918      1.36   1.26    0.0847 -0.280   0.699      0.114  -0.582     2018
   # 4      4   -0.811 -0.379 -2.09      -0.361  0.397   -0.782  0.110 -0.0187     -0.641 -0.149   -1.47  -2.45  -1.27       0.418  0.131   0.0582  0.885   0.784      0.998  -0.0115    2018
   # 5      5   -2.99  -2.90   0.956      0.643  0.733    0.165  0.382  1.46        1.48   2.16    -0.451 -0.213 -0.357      0.222  0.686  -0.949  -0.156   1.23       1.35    0.908     2018
   # 6      6   -1.04  -0.322  1.96       1.30   1.64     0.838 -0.406  1.86        0.863  2.11     0.479  2.37  -1.13      -1.22  -1.63   -0.970   0.0391 -1.08       0.683  -1.24      2018
   df1b <- ... %>%
     .[, yearRef := 2018 ] %>%
     .[order(.),]
   head(df1b)
   #    yearID x1_h.end.val   x1_h.val   x1_m.val x1_p.start.val   x1_p.val x2_h.end.val   x2_h.val    x2_m.val x2_p.start.val   x2_p.val x3_h.end.val   x3_h.val   x3_m.val x3_p.start.val   x3_p.val x4_h.end.val    x4_h.val    x4_m.val x4_p.start.val    x4_p.val yearRef
   # 1:      1    1.3048697  1.2421556  1.9237647     -0.1061245  1.4053975   -0.9901743 -3.5367198 -2.28861552      0.5730634 -0.5164756    2.0842981  2.2819246  0.4609628      0.7670651  0.4546020  -0.48256993 -0.32607779 -0.09748514    -0.05589648 -1.10933614    2018
   # 2:      2   -0.1719174 -1.9532258  1.0134748     -2.6564554 -5.0969223    1.2498633  1.5136450  0.60537738      0.3422707 -0.5457969   -1.3790815 -0.7305400  0.4429124     -0.7249950 -1.1681343  -0.62293711 -1.90725766  1.48980773    -0.80634526 -0.71692479    2018
   # 3:      3    0.5049551 -0.1039713  1.7399409     -0.6399949 -0.1845448    0.5697303  1.6768675 -2.24285021     -0.1029872 -1.0245616   -1.3608773 -2.5029906 -0.9178704      1.3641160  1.2619892   0.08468983 -0.27967757  0.69899862     0.11429665 -0.58216791    2018
   # 4:      4   -0.8113932 -0.3785752 -2.0949859     -0.3610573  0.3971059   -0.7823128  0.1098614 -0.01867344     -0.6414615 -0.1488759   -1.4653210 -2.4476336 -1.2718183      0.4179297  0.1311655   0.05823201  0.88484095  0.78382293     0.99795594 -0.01147192    2018
   # 5:      5   -2.9930901 -2.9032572  0.9558396      0.6428993  0.7326600    0.1645109  0.3819658  1.45532687      1.4820236  2.1608213   -0.4513016 -0.2129462 -0.3572757      0.2221201  0.6855960  -0.94859958 -0.15646638  1.23051588     1.34645936  0.90755241    2018
   # 6:      6   -1.0431189 -0.3222408  1.9592347      1.3025426  1.6383908    0.8379162 -0.4059827  1.86142674      0.8626753  2.1076609    0.4792767  2.3683451 -1.1252801     -1.2213407 -1.6339743  -0.96979464  0.03912882 -1.08199221     0.68254513 -1.23950872    2018
   ```

They do match:

```r
identical(as.data.frame(df1a), as.data.frame(df1b))
# [1] TRUE
```

The speed-ups are not gargantuan, but they do appear to be significant. One way you can speed up your own code (still `dplyr`) is to remove the `group`ing as soon as you don't need it. If I add `ungroup()` immediately after `summarise(...)`, I see a small improvement.

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  dplyr = { ... },
  dplyr_ungrp = { ... },
  data.table = { ... },
  times = 10
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#        dplyr 988.8311 1021.4725 1048.5462 1045.6885 1066.2733 1135.6032    10
#  dplyr_ungrp 909.3643  913.9301  952.6282  937.6540  998.2802 1041.2144    10
#   data.table 457.4500  465.1788  478.1471  474.2388  478.9840  531.1449    10
```